# Drm protected video play on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-emulator, android-tv

Is there any way to play DRM(Digital Right Management) content on Android TV Emulator for testing?
if device not support widevine drm , how to make it supported, is there any way?
Or Is there any other Tv emulator which can support this?

I used Jwplayer(wrapper for exoplayer) for playing the video. Tried on real device, it worked. But I need to test it on android tv emulator.

on emulator it throws error below:

Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: android.media.MediaDrmException: Attempting to open a session using a dummy ExoMediaDrm.

Comment: DRM uses security by obfuscation so it is a bit complex to test. You will need DRM licenses for the content you want to test.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.